# Adding request scope in Spring results in java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'request'

Tags: java, spring, embedded-tomcat-8

I have an issue where I am not able to add request beans in spring with Embedded Tomcat 9.0.5

methode Which Would Launch The Application

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
srv = new Tomcat();
    srv.getConnector().setPort(port);
    ctx = srv.addContext("", new File("").getAbsolutePath());
    srv.addServlet(ctx, "testServlet",  new TestServlet());
    ctx.addServletMappingDecoded("/testServlet/*", "testServlet");

    ctx.addApplicationListener(RequestContextListener.class.getName());
    try {
        srv.start();
    } catch (LifecycleException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

services.xml

```
<bean id="service" class="xxxx.xx.ServiceImpl" scope="request">
</bean>
```

When I start apache in spring boot I get followingerror:

```
|main|noSessionId|noCorrelationId|ERROR|NULL|null|java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope name 'request'
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1342)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1249)
```

Comment: NB: Spring with Embedded Tomcat without Spring Boot

Comment: What version of Spring do you use?

Comment: No Scope registered for scope `'requesrt'`, isn't the spelling of request wrong?

Comment: which version of spring are u using? you find the different scopes here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes

Comment: what is this services.xml ?Are you using Spring MVC? If yes, have you configured dispacther servlet. If no, what web-aware Spring ApplicationContext are you using as I mentioned in answer request scope is only for web-aware Spring ApplicationContext. Show your pom.xml

Comment: i'm using spring-web, spring-core version 4.3.14.RELEASE. error : No Scope registered for scope name 'request'

Comment: Please add your pom.xml Also you need spring mvc with spring web to run a web app.

Comment: For information: i have no error when lunching application and i can access the controler without error.

Comment: the contenet of pom.xml is:

Comment: dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>  
      <version>4.3.14.RELEASE</version> 
    </dependency>  
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>  
      <version>4.3.14.RELEASE</version>  
      <exclusions> 
        <exclusion>

Answer (score 3):

Spring request, session, global session and application scope are meant for Spring web application.
Spring request scope is related to HTTP request.
Spring session scope is related to HTTP session.
Spring application scope is related to ServletContext.
Spring global session scope is related to spring portlet application.
It means we can not use these scopes in standalone application.

The following is mentioned in Spring Doc:https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes

> The request, session, application, and websocket scopes are only
>   available if you use a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext
>   implementation (such as XmlWebApplicationContext). If you use these
>   scopes with regular Spring IoC containers such as the
>   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext, an IllegalStateException will be
>   thrown complaining about an unknown bean scope.